# overriding Magento toolbar.phtml file

Tags: search, toolbar, phtml

I am editing the file `\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\product\list\toolbar.phtml` through my own module. I want to specify the available categories on the current list.

***Example:*** I search for "**shirt**" and the products that contains "shirt" is in 2 categories: **summer** and **winter**.

The idea is that the user can filter by (not order by) one of the two categories available.
I searched this function:

```
<?php foreach ($this->getAvailableLimit() as  $_key=>$_limit): ?>
```

*I found out that it only works with specific attributes of product and only for "order by", but what about the categories? and if I want to "filter by"?*

Is that possible? Any ideas?

Thanks!

I response to myself:

**I do it!**

On the one hand I copied the file `toolbar.php` to override it (and add my personalized functions) and secondly the `List.php` file to edit the collection list and add my **category_id** filter. Finally I edited my `toolbar.phtml` file to add the dropdown list with available categories and get the **categoryId** param to keep selected the category in the dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

You can make categories filterable in the layered navigation.  In the admin, if you set the category setting *"Is Anchor?"*, that category will become a filterable attribute.  This way you don't have customize it in the toolbar filters.

Comment: I don't need the default filter layered navigation, because in the template that we are using is deactivated. Thanks for your answer anyway.